# Function to iterate and doing Arithmetic operation with Json nested keys

Tags: javascript, json, vuejs2

I need to create a function to iterate on a json object 'menu' returning me some json nested keys. With three of these keys I need to realise some simple arithmetic operations like following: 
First I need to add all the `potatoes`, then I should multiply all the `tomatoes` by this `beef` then divide the result by `carrots` . Note that all the keys are equal to numbers so the calculation will be similar to : (8*2.083488+40*1.5) / (180+180)

**Note** that my object is a computed properties and should be show in the vue template (but I think that's not the most important thing for me actually)

Thanks in advance and if you need more explaination I am around

Here is my function:

```
   myFunc: function() {
      var array = JSON.parse(totalMenu);
      array.forEach(function(object) {
       console.log(object.carrots);
      });
    }
```

Here's the JSON (include inside totalMenu object) :

```
      {
      "foo32":[
        {
            "dates":[
                {
                    "date":"2018-04-02",
                    "foo":[
                        {
                            "foo78":[
                                {
                                    "fooId":1
                                }
                            ],
                            "foo54":2.636000,
                            "beef":2.083488,
                            "foo09":0,
                            "foo":"",
                            "potatoes":8,
                            "foo90":0,
                            "foo55":0,
                            "fooLabel":"360 cheese nana "
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "date":"2018-04-03",
                    "fooReceipe":[
                        {
                            "foo65":0,
                            "fooID":"FX0000010000984",
                            "foo21":0,
                            "foo74":1,
                            "foo75":[
                                {
                                    "foo89":"NOR",
                                    "foo67":1
                                }
                            ],
                            "foo34":2.636000,
                            "beef":1.50,
                            "foo58":0,
                            "foo5":"",
                            "potatoes":40,
                            "foo2":0,
                            "foo":0,
                            "familleLabel":"Plate for nowhere "
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "familyLabel":"Starter",
            "fammilyreceipe":13,
            "family":7
        }
    ],
    "foo23":1002,
    "totalfoo":[
        {
            "foo4":0,
            "foo2":"2018-04-02",
            "foo":0,
            "carrots":180
        },
        {
            "foo3":0,
            "foo2":"2018-04-03",
            "foo":0,
            "carrots":180
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Note that your JSON is not entirely valid: the key `foo54` is duplicated (keys must be unique). Also, this seems like an X-Y problem: why is the JSON output so messy with all the different types of nesting levels? A more appropriate solution will be: (1) fixing and somewhat flattening the JSON output and (2) working out the correct logic in your VueJS parser.

Comment: @Terry ahright that is a mistake I did when I replaced they keys for the exemple, I update my post

Comment: @Terry According to the specification of [JSON](https://www.json.org/), it says "An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs", meaning as long as the value is different, it is valid a valid set, and hence valid JSON

Comment: @Ferrybig He had the same key declared twice in the same level--even though the spec does not mention whether unique keys are allowed, most implementations will go with keeping the last key-value pair after parsing it, e.g. `var x = { "foo54": 123, "foo54": "lorem" }` you will get `lorem` if you call `x['foo54']`. Look at the edit history and you will see what could've gone wrong. However, this is not related to the issue he has at hand: it wast just a heads up, if that is actually his real JSON output.

Comment: Thanks guys and what about my issue?

Comment: "Here's the JSON:" That's not JSON, it's JavaScript.

Comment: It's the Json but I include it to a variable just to unterstand to ligic I tried but in my project I can't do that.. I edit my post